# How to create a function that would be available for all schemas?

Tags: postgresql, functions

How can we create a function in a PostgreSQL database so it would be available for all schemas?

Also, is there a way to create a function that would be available for all databases and all schemas as well?

Comment: So is this question answered properly?

Answer (score 2):

**Every** function is available "for all schemas" in the same database. Schemas per se do not restrict access at all. (Executing roles need the necessary privileges of course.) If the schema is not listed in the `search_path` of your session, schema-qualify like:

```
SELECT my_schema.my_function();
```

**No** function is available from another database.

You may be confusing the concepts of *schema* and *database* (and *cluster*). Basics here:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-overview.html

Or you may be unaware how the schema `search_path` works. See:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860)